# How do I get rid of Python Tkinter root window?

Tags: python, winapi, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Do you know a smart way to hide or in any other way get rid of the root window  that appears, opened by `Tk()`? I would like just to use a normal dialog.

Should I skip the dialog and put all my components in the root window? Is it possible or desirable? Or is there a smarter solution?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Probably the vast majority of of tk-based applications place all the components in the default root window. This is the most convenient way to do it since it already exists. Choosing to hide the default window and create your own is a perfectly fine thing to do, though it requires just a tiny bit of extra work.

To answer your specific question about how to hide it, use the [withdraw](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.withdraw-method) method of the root window:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
```

If you want to make the window visible again, call the [deiconify](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.deiconify-method) (or wm_deiconify) method.

```
root.deiconify()
```

Once you are done with the dialog, you can destroy the root window along with all other tkinter widgets with the [destroy](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.destroy-method) method:

```
root.destroy()
```

Comment: So on StackOverflow there are solutions using .destroy(), tkinter.Toplevel(self).destroy(), quit(), tkinter.Toplevel(self).quit(), withdraw(), iconify() to choose from. Nice. Except that not a single one works... I did "top_lev = tkinter.Toplevel(label); label.master.destroy();label.destroy();top_lev.destroy();root = tkinter.Tk();root.withdraw();root.destroy()" which works like a charm (some sarcasm involved).

Comment: @deusexmachina: they all work if you use them propertly, but they all have different purposes. Though `.quit()` and `.destroy()` are effectively identical.

Comment: @BryanOakley I see. Having differently named methods to do the same thing is still quite nasty though IMHO.

Comment: @deusexmachina: all of these methods do different things. And in the case of `destroy()` you can use it on any widget. It only behaves like `.quit()` when you call it on the root window, and even then there are differences. It's just that most apps will never take advantage of the differences.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code here causes a "flash" as the window is created and then hidden.  I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 15):

I haven't tested since I don't have any Python/TKinter environment, but try this.

In pure Tk there's a method called "wm" to manage the windows. There you can do something like "wm withdraw .mywindow" where '.mywindow' is a toplevel.

In TkInter you should be able to do something similar to:

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw() # won't need this
```

If you want to make the window visible again, call the [deiconify](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.deiconify-method) (or wm_deiconify) method.

```
root.deiconify()
```

Comment: how do you get the window back on top?

Comment: @IcyFlame: you do `root.deiconify()` to get the window to reappear.

Comment: thank you sir, I had already asked that question and got an answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967690/showing-a-window-that-was-hidden-using-root-withdraw-in-tkinter

Answer (score 11):

On OSX, iconify seems to work better:

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.iconify()
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want there to a be "flash" as the window is created, use this slight variation:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.withdraw()
```

Answer (score 3):

I need to check whether it's `withdrawn` or not, below is the solution.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
print(root.wm_state())
if root.wm_state() == 'withdrawn':  # <----
    root.iconify()
root.mainloop()
```

[withdraw](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.withdraw-method)

> Removes the window from the screen (**without destroying it**). To redraw the window, use deiconify.
> When the window has been withdrawn, the state method returns *"withdrawn"*.

[deiconify](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.deiconify-method)

> redraw the window

[iconify](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.iconify-method)

> Turns the window into an icon (**without destroying it**).
> To redraw the window, use deiconify. Under Windows, the window will show up in the *taskbar*.
> When the window has been iconified, the state method returns

[state](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.state-method)

> normal, iconify, withdrawn, icon

Answer (score 0):

This way will work fine:

```
import Tkinter as tk 
root = tk.Tk() 
root.withdraw()
```

Or this one:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.withdraw()
```

Two things you must not forget:

1. Don forget to import the class:

   import tkinter as tk
2. Place the above commands in the main windows, **outside ANY FUNCTION**

Comment: In python 3.x it is called `tkinter` and not `Tkinter`.

Comment: Um, how is this different from my answer (posted 4 years prior)?

Answer (score -2):

For Python 3.0 and higher, to hide the window you need to write the following:

```
import tkinter
tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
```

Comment: Is'nt this the same as was suggested by @BryanOakley ten years ago?

Answer (score -2):

```
root.deiconify()
root.withdraw()
```

Comment: Please tell us why and how it could work.