# How to show a window that was hidden using "withdraw" method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I would like to show a window after I called `withdraw`.

The following is my current code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def callback():    
    global root
    root.withdraw()
    win2 = Tk()

root = Tk()
Label(root,text='this is a window').pack()
Button(root,text='withdraw',command=self.callback).pack()
mainloop()
```

As soon as I press the button, the window disappears much as I want it, and another window appears and everything works great. How do I get the first window back, in the same state as it was before?

Comment: One important detail: callback functions are not subprocesses. They run on the same thread than the Tkinter code, and the GUI freezes if they take too long. If it was a subprocess, you couldn't access global variables from that function.

Comment: You should never create two instances of `Tk` -- Tkinter simply isn't designed to work that way. If you need multiple windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the following commands when you want to show the window:

```
# root.update()  # not required
root.deiconify()
```

If you want to know more about it, see [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/26/tkinter-how-to-show-hide-a-window/).

Comment: Does that mean it is not required??