# Extra window doesn't close with Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog

test = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", initialfile="file.txt", 
                                  multiple=False, title="Please Select Your File")
```

But when it pops up, there are two windows and not one. There is "Please select Your File", and an empty window with a symbol and the words "tk". How do I get rid of the second window?

Edit to show my question is different:

But, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1407668/5155994) it says that withdraw only hides it. Considering that, how would I make the invisible window close? Would it be

```
tk.Tk().destroy()
```

After that?

Comment: @nbro But, from there it says that withdraw only hides it. Considering that, how would I make the invisible window close? Would it be `tk.Tk().destroy()`

After that?

Comment: It will be destroyed once the program terminates, but theoretically I think you could call `destroy` or `quit` after closing the dialog...

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406145/how-do-i-get-rid-of-python-tkinter-root-window, but I've edited the accepted answer to address how to destroy the root window.