# Two windows: First Login after that main program

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

i have this program

```
class loginWindow():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        master.title(u"Geometry Calc - Login")
        Button(master, text="Login", command=self.login).pack()

    def login(self):
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        main(self.newWindow)
        self.master.withdraw()


class main():
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Nastavení nového okna
        master.title(u"Geometry Calc")  # Nadpis
        master.geometry("695x935")  # Rozmery v px
        master.config(background="white")
        master.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)  # Zakážeme změnu rozměrů uživatelem - zatím..

        menubar = Menu(master)

        helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Konec", command=master.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Soubor", menu=helpmenu)
        helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="O programu", command=self.createAbout)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Pomoc", menu=helpmenu)
        master.config(menu=menubar)

        canvas = Canvas(master, width=691, height=900)
        canvas.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
        self.showImage(canvas, 347, 454, "geometry_table.jpg")


root = Tk()
app = loginWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
`
```

and i have this problem. When i run my program, i can see **login window**, when i hit login button I get window **main**, but window **login** is only withdrawed. So when i close window **main** my program still run. And i need make this. First run program **main**, but will be invisible or something. And i see only login window (maybe Toplevel). When i hit button login the window **loginWindow** will get destroy() and the window **main** will be visible

Comment: [How do I get rid of Python Tkinter root window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406145/how-do-i-get-rid-of-python-tkinter-root-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Toplevel` for login window and `withdraw` , `deiconify` methods to hide and show root window respectively.

Check the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *


class loginWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        # Save parent reference to use it 
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title(u"Geometry Calc - Login")
        Button(self, text="Login", command=self.login).pack()

    def login(self):

        access =  True # Used to test if a user can login.

        if access:
            # Close Toplevel window and show root window
            self.destroy()
            self.parent.deiconify()
        else:
            self.parent.quit()



class main(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title(u"Geometry Calc")  # Nadpis
        self.geometry("695x935")  # Rozmery v px
        self.config(background="white")
        self.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)  # Zakážeme změnu rozměrů uživatelem - zatím..

        menubar = Menu(self)

        helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Konec", command=self.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Soubor", menu=helpmenu)
        helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="O programu", command=self.createAbout)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Pomoc", menu=helpmenu)
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        canvas = Canvas(self, width=691, height=900)
        canvas.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

        # Hide root window
        self.withdraw()

        # Lunch login window
        loginWindow('Frame', self)


    def createAbout(self):
        pass

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()



app = main()

app.mainloop()
```

If youn want to use 2 Toplevel windows for login and main app, `root window` should be hidden:

```
class loginWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        ...

    def login(self):
       if access:
            # Close Toplevel window and lunch root window
            self.destroy()
            main()



class main(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ...



root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

loginWindow('title', root)

root.mainloop()
```