# How do I keep the current tkinter window and update it using a push button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a UI and after I click the widget button the next Tkinter should be permanent. In this permanent Tkinter window, I need to click a hardware button for other purposes like capture an image. This is the image of my UI [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Hmq.png) then after clicking the "Click here button another UI will show up like this [Next UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHpwt.png). How do I keep this next UI and use a hardware push button to update the text label? This is the code I have done so far for this UI.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("480x320")

root['bg']='white'
PlayerTwo=PhotoImage(file="2.png")
PlayerThree=PhotoImage(file="3.png")
PlayerFour=PhotoImage(file="4.png")

players_label = tk.Label(root,
                         text="CHOOSE THE NUMBER OF PLAYERS THAT WILL BE PLAYING",
                         font="Times 13",
                         fg="white",
                         bg="#85C1E9")
players_label.pack(fill=X,ipady=40)


#No. of players and button for players name
b0 = tk.Button(root, text="Click here after player credentials", command=determine_players)
b0.pack(fill=X, ipady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

And this code is after clicking the UI widget button

```
def determine_players():
top = tk.Tk()
top.geometry("480x320")
text_file = open("players.txt", "r")
message = text_file.read()
players = message.split()
point1 = 0
point2 = 1
#print(players)
if len(players) == 2:

    proc = ImageProcess()
    img = cv2.imread("array_try/Character_extract_image1.jpg")

    print(proc.frame_table(img))
    Player1 = players[0]  
    Player2 = players[1]
    player1 = tk.Label(top,
                         text=Player1,
                         font="Times 45",
                         fg="white",
                         bg="#0000FF")
    #player1.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10, anchor= N)
    player1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    player1.config(width=7)


    text1 = tk.Text(top, heigh=30, width=30)

    pickle_in = open("game_file.pickle","rb")
    example_dict = pickle.load(pickle_in)

    text1.insert(tk.INSERT,example_dict[point1])
    text1.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='N')
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at this answer by WaKo: [Two windows: First Login after that main program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159791/two-windows-first-login-after-that-main-program) . I have been working with Tkinter GUI's and I found that this solution is best for having an initial window and then another.  The key functions are Toplevel, destroy, deiconify, and withdraw.  You can move any relevant data from the Toplevel to the master window very easily.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll see to it. Thank you.