# Tkinter opens two windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using python 3.6 and have the following issue.
These lines of codes apparently open two windows, but I only expect one to be opened.

```
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

file_name = asksaveasfilename()
root.withdraw()
```

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: no but it doesnt matter, i tried it without all the rest it is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do `filename = asksaveasfilename()` you call the function
and that makes tkinter open the second window put that in a function and on
a button click the second window will open

```
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
asksaveasfilename()
```

Comment: Sorry I dont get it. tkiner opens a seconde windwo because why?

Comment: and I dont want a button, the window should open whene the code is executed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406145/how-do-i-get-rid-of-python-tkinter-root-window?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 4):

IIRC, you're supposed to call `withdraw` *before* you call `asksaveasfilename`. Same as in [Choosing a file in Python with simple Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579568/953482).

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
file_name = asksaveasfilename()
```