# Tkinter: Keep from moving focus to window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an on screen keyboard. It works for widgets in the window but when I press a button it moves focus from the window I am trying to type in to the window that has the buttons. How do I prevent python from moving?

```
from tkinter import *
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.entry = Entry()
        self.buttonOne = Button(text='1')
        self.buttonTwo = Button(text='2')
        self.buttonThree = Button(text='3')
        self.buttonOne.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, keyPressed='1': self.pressed(event, keyPressed))
        self.buttonTwo.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, keyPressed='2': self.pressed(event, keyPressed))
        self.buttonThree.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, keyPressed='3': self.pressed(event, keyPressed))
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
        self.buttonOne.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.buttonTwo.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.buttonThree.grid(row=1, column=2)
    def pressed(self, event, keyPressed):
        keyboard.press(keyPressed)
        keyboard.release(keyPressed)
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `withdraw()` and `deiconify()`. This will make it so the window with the button is invisible once you call it on that window. Once you use `deiconify()` it reverses this and makes it visible again.

More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406145/how-do-i-get-rid-of-python-tkinter-root-window).

Comment: This solution provides the functionality I am looking for, however you see see the window 'flash'(go away with withdraw() and comeback with deiconify()). I solved this with drawing the window twice in the same location so that the flash is not noticabel but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it without having to create the same window twice.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: Keep from moving focus to window

On X11, you can set the `-type` attribute:

```
self.wm_attributes("-type", 'dock')
```

`'dock'` will working for me not to grab the focus, but are not supported by all window managers.

---

**Reference**:

- [`wm attributes`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm)

  > Communicate with window manager
- [A list of types](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm#M19)

  > **`-type`**
  >   Requests that the window should be interpreted by the window manager as being of the specified type(s). This may cause the window to be decorated in a different way or otherwise managed differently, though exactly what happens is entirely up to the window manager.
  >
  > **`'dock'`**
  >     indicates a dock/panel feature,

---

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.wm_attributes("-type", 'dock')

        for n in range(64, 68):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=chr(n), takefocus=0)
            btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_click)
            btn.pack()

    def on_click(self, event):
        w = event.widget
        print(w['text'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```