# Set master TopLevel when tk.NoDefaultRoot is set

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a little confused as to how this function works. I want to have the master window be a separate toplevel I create.

```
tk.NoDefaultRoot()
root = tk.Tk()
root.master = tk.Toplevel()
root.mainloop()
```

If I attempt to do something like this I get an attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When *default root feature* is enabled (it is default enabled) and you create a widget without passing the parent argument, it will use the *default root* created either implicitly or explicitly.

However if *default root* feature is disabled by executing `tk.NoDefaultRoot()`, then the *default root* will not be used or created for you.

You need to pass the root instance to `Toplevel()` explicitly: `tk.Toplevel(root)`.

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense. I thought that NoDefaultRoot would prevent the program from creating the main window, but from your explanation I can see that's not what it's intended for. I'll follow Bryan's answer here: [Correct way to hide main window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406145/how-do-i-get-rid-of-python-tkinter-root-window)