How can I killing the mainloop window without causing a _!canvas TclError
fluff
After I watched a whole tutorial on YT on Python, I decided to create a program utilising the Tkinter library, specifically the You Are An Idiot virus (no offense). However, due to the limitations of the library (or my brain), it seems that I cannot utilise multithreading on it, which led me to instead count time using ticks.
end of fluff
The main issue now is that I am trying to make more windows as I close the main one, but the thing is that when I close the main window, the other widgets run causing a _!canvas TclError, making it very hard for me to find a way around it.
I wanted to see if there was a solution for this, or do I just move on to another project (and maybe try this in the future using other programming languages.)
Code below:
'''
Ver 1.1 - Updated variable names,

'''
from tkinter import *
import time
import pygame
import threading

test = True

mw = Tk()

def common_properties(self, window):
    if mw.winfo_exists():
        icon = PhotoImage(file="smile.png")
        self.canvas.pack()    
        mw.iconphoto(True, icon)
        mw.title("YOU ARE AN IDIOT")
        while mw.winfo_exists():
            move(self)
            change_colour(self)

mw.mainloop()

def move(self):
    if mw.winfo_exists():
        bounds = self.canvas.bbox(self.text)
        text_height = bounds[3] - bounds[1]
        if bounds[2]>= self.width or bounds[0]<0:
            self.xVelocity = -self.xVelocity
        if bounds[1]>= self.height - text_height or bounds[1]<0:
            self.yVelocity = -self.yVelocity
        self.canvas.move(self.text, self.xVelocity, self.yVelocity)
        mw.update()
        time.sleep(0.001)

def change_colour(self):
    if mw.winfo_exists():
        if self.is_colourinversed > 0 and self.is_colourinversed <= 1:
            self.is_colourinversed = round(self.is_colourinversed -0.005, 3)
            if self.is_colourinversed == 0:
                self.is_colourinversed = -1
        elif self.is_colourinversed < 0 and self.is_colourinversed >= -1:
            self.is_colourinversed = round(self.is_colourinversed +0.005, 3)
            if self.is_colourinversed == -0.005:
                self.is_colourinversed = 1
        time.sleep(0.001)
        if self.is_colourinversed < 2 and self.is_colourinversed > 0:
            self.canvas.config(bg="black")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text, fill="white")
        else:
            self.canvas.config(bg="white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text, fill="black")

def play():
    if mw.winfo_exists():
        pygame.mixer.music.load("y2mate.com - sans.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    

class MainWindow():
        
    def __init__(self, xVelocity, yVelocity, height, width, font_size) -> None:
        self.is_colourinversed = -1
        self.xVelocity = xVelocity
        self.yVelocity = yVelocity
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.font_size = font_size

        self.canvas = Canvas(mw, height=self.height, width=self.width)
        self.text = self.canvas.create_text(1,0, text="you are an idiot\n  ☺    ☺    ☺", font=("Times New Roman", self.font_size), anchor=NW)
        pygame.mixer.init()
        play()
        common_properties(self, mw)

            
        
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    while True:
        test = True
        while test:
            MainWindow(1.4, 1.4, 400, 400, 30)
            test = False

I tried to look up related solutions on stackoverflow, like how to exit the mainloop without causing an error, or some function that could detect if the window was destroyed or not. However, I only found winfo_exists(), which was unusuable since it CAUSED an error, and some ways like exception handling, but I needed it to trigger the creation of other windows.

You can put it in a try/catch or use mw.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_window_close) like this. Also to stop the mainloop without closing the window, you can use mw.quit()

The function .protocol() doesn't integrate well to my program, since it is continuously running on a while True loop, and adding to the sleep command, it just makes the program freeze. The .quit() doesn't work either for me for some reason, so even when I call the function it keeps running.

this code as posted here will fault with a NameError on the line mw.mainloop(). Please fix this for whatever code you have working without killing the root window.
BTW: you  should not kill the root window - :-)  that is your problem. Just hide it, if neede, with mw.withdraw() (check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406145/how-do-i-get-rid-of-python-tkinter-root-window )

Also please provide a minimal reproducible example. This way, you might find the problem yourself

@oskar wym by minimal reproducible example? I didn't get it sry

@jsbueno Also, thank you very much, it worked like wonders :D

To close a tkinter window without an error, use destroy and quit commands. Firstly, you have to use mw.destroy() and then mw.quit()
Example:
from tkinter import *

mw = Tk()

    def destroy_window():
        mw.destroy()
        mw.quit()

mw.mainloop()

To destroy the window, simply use the function destroy_window() like so.
I hope this helped!

Thank you for the help, but you can see on the comments of the original post saying it didn't work (Since another person has suggested me a similar solution). Nonetheless, thank you for your time helping my dumb question.

No question of curiosity is dumb. :)

Also, wanted to ask you if you knew how could I implement the animation to multiple windows, since mines work only on the most recent window
